# 9 Different material to one texture file

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, texture-baking, baking

I am trying to bake Different materials to one texture file. I tried a few tutorials on Youtube and followed a few guides here on this forum. How ever none of them are working for me. Everytime when I try to bake it is just black. If somebody could help me I would be very pleased! I am using Blenden 2.92 but I have also tried it on 2.8 and 2.79 [Google link for my model](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wQpa1eNP4k1tPMAwK5PfXNDXTq6VHx7d/view?usp=sharing) I have include my model at my google drive.

Comment: what kind of bake are you trying to do? Duplicate your object, unwrap it, give it a new image texture, in the Bake panel choose the Selected to Active option and the Bake Type you want (if you just want the Diffuse, select Diffuse and, below, enable Color only), select the original object, shift select the copy, bake it, it should work

Comment: @moonboots Thank for the reaction! I followed your instruction and well I didnt work for some reason... I made an video of it to show it   ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQsA-yV1-y8 ) . It looks like it is baking to diffrent textures. I hope you could help me further? Thanks!

Comment: it's hard to follow, here is a more precise description: Duplicate your object, unwrap it (Smart UV Project mode), delete all the materials of the copy, create a new one called Bake for example, give it an Image Texture node with a new image, in the Bake panel choose the Selected to Active option and the Bake Type you want (if you just want the Diffuse, select Diffuse and, below, enable Color only), select the original object, shift select the copy, bake it...

Comment: @moonboots Thanks I got it to work! Thank you so much!